# how to call a sql server function from hibernate with return parameter?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a function in SQL server and I want to call it from hibernate.
I have tested these 2 methods but no one was successful.
First method:

```
Session sixSession=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Query q2=sixSession.createQuery("from dbo.old_remaining(?)").setParameter("paymentVcode", p_Vcode);
        q2.getNamedParameters();
        List list=sixSession.getNamedQuery("{dbo.old_remaining(?)}").setString(1,"p_Vcode").list();
```

dbo.old_remaining is my function and p_Vcode is an int

the error is:

```
unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 23 [from dbo.old_remaining(?)]
```

Second method:

```
Float var;
List li=session.getNamedQuery("{dbo.old_remaining(?)}")  
    .setString(1, var).list();
```

The error is:
org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: {dbo.old_remaining(?)}

Please Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can propose one work around based on CallableStatement. This standard jdbc statement to call functions:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        CallableStatement callable = connection.prepareCall("{? = call dbo.old_remaining(?)}");
        callable.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.FLOAT );
        callable.setString(2, "your string parameter");
        callable.execute();
        float functionResult = callable.getFloat(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Error invoking Action using Hibernate Core Session / Transaction injection
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '{'.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:213)

Comment: Yes, change it: "{? = call dbo.old_remaining(?)}". Foget add call.

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT dbo.old_remaining(?)");
        pstmt.setString(1,p_Vcode);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while( rs.next() )
        System.out.println( rs.getFloat(1) ) ;
    }
});
```